# <br/> getting rendered as text and not page break on page

Tags: asp.net, html

I have some text coming from xml file text reads as `&li;br/ &gt;` which after Html.Decode becomes `<br/>` but since i am not using any server controls this gets displayed as `<br/>` text rather than a page break. Any clues.

Comment: Exactly how are you outputting the markup? Otherwise, this is decidedly vague.

Comment: In what control is the text being used? Is it being put into a `label.Text` for example? Quick and dirty do `text.Replace("<br/>",vbCrLf)` or `text.Replace(@"<br/>","\n")` for C#

Comment: I am using HtmlGenericControl and creating ul and li elements for creating a navigation. The li HtmlGenericControil in turn has another HtmlGeneriControl to create an anchor tag. The text coming from xml gets assinged to innerText property of the HtmlGenericControl used for anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comment you are assigning the text `<br/>` to the [InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext.aspx) property of a variable instance of the class [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx).

Your problem is the text is escaped (try viewing the source of the rendered page) so that it renders as text.  Use the [InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx) property instead to write out pre-formatted HTML in a HtmlGenericControl instance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion thats what i thought

Answer (score 0):

There are *much* better ways (and nicer ways) but

```
text.Replace("<br/>",vbCrLf)   'VB
```

or

```
text.Replace(@"<br/>","\n")     //C#
```

Comment: Or use `Environment.NewLine` in both languages for consistency, depending on how crazy you're feeling.

Comment: I was using InnerText property which will not get rendered. Using InnerHtml solved the issue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Set InnerHtml of HtmlGenericControl instead of innerText
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx